# Ошибка при объявлении переменных: initializer element is not constant

Tags: c, const

При объявлении

```
const double X_max = 8701859.625360, X_min = -8701859.625360;
double X_Curr = X_max, X_Step = 100021.375000, Y_Curr = 7641389.500000, H_Curr = 84.972000;
```

компилятор ругается на вторую строчку:

> initializer element is not constant

Понимаю, что, скорее всего, ошибка глупая, но все же подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Начать стоит с упрощения примера: уберите лишнее, сохранив ошибку. Так Вам станет понятнее, что происходит. `const double X_max = 8701859.625360; double X_Curr = X_max;`

Comment: Вы недостаточно полно описали контекст. Ключевым моментом в данном случае является то, что эти переменные у вас объявлены на уровне файла. В локальном объявлении такой ошибки не было бы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тонкость вот в чём: в C переменные с модификатором `const` не являются в полном смысле константными (к чему мы привыкли в C++). Константные выражения должны быть константными в момент компиляции, что в Вашем примере не выполняется. Традиционный выход из этой ситуации такой:

```
#define X_max 8701859.625360
double X_Curr = X_max;
```

Comment: А в чём разница? Макрос же всё равно разворачивается препроцессором, и компилятор в любом случае получает присваивание простого числа.

Comment: Ну да, макрос разворачивается без проблем. А недо-константная-переменная так не работает в C (вот в C++ так разрешено писать, что естественно и логично).

Comment: @Arhad: Так мы и хотим получить "присваивание простого числа". "Простое число" в С является *константой*, а вот const-переменная - не является.

Answer (score 1):

Вы недостаточно полно описали контекст. Ключевым моментом в данном случае является то, что эти переменные у вас объявлены *на уровне файла* и, следовательно, обладают *статическим классом хранения* (static storage duration). В языке С все объекты со статическим классом хранения можно инициализировать только константными выражениями.

Переменные, объявленные с `const`, в языке С не являются константными выражениями. Поэтому инициализация

```
double X_Curr = X_max, ...
```

(именно и только эта) является ошибочной.

По этой причине для объявления именованных констант в языке С предпочтительно используется `#define` или `enum`, а не `const`.

То же самое объявление, но сделанное внутри блока, не будет приводить к такой ошибке, ибо на него требование инициализации константами не распространяется. Но стоит добавить туда ключевое слово `static`, как ошибка возникнет опять.