# Ошибка при объявлении int - "initializer element is not constant"

Tags: c++, c

Начал изучать язык Си. Пытаюсь скомпилировать простенькую программку, и выбивает такую ошибку. Прочекал весь интернет, но не смог решить. Не подскажите где меня подстрелили? Спасибо.
Это ошибка:

```
hello.c:4:1: error: initializer element is not constantint rand_num = rand() % 11;
```

Это мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rand_num = rand() % 11;
int sup_num;

void probability();

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(sup_num != rand_num) {
        printf("What is my number?");
        scanf("%d", &sup_num);
        probability();
    }
    return 0;
}

void probability() {
    if(sup_num > rand_num) {
        printf("My number is bigger\n");
    } else if(sup_num < rand_num) {
        printf("My number is less\n");
    } else {
        printf("Gotcha! It is my number!");
    }
```

}

Comment: А можете, всё таки, привести код?

Может это..? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558734/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-initializer-element-is-not-constant

Comment: @loverx код забыл прилепит, простите. Смотрел, не помогло(

Comment: Почему на вопросе сразу два тэга: [tag:C] и [tag:C++]? Особенно  в вопросе, где эти языки принципиально отличаются. При чём здесь [tag:C++]?

Comment: глобально вы не можете вызвать функцию  (rand в вашем случаи) и к тому же глобальный обьект должен  быть инициализирован конкретным значением

Answer (score 7):

В языке С не допускается использование неконстантных значений для инициализации объектов со статическим классом памяти. Об этом вам открытым текстом и говорит компилятор.

То есть для переменной типа `int`, объявленной на уровне файла, инициализатором может служить `0` или `42`, но ни в коем случае не `rand() % 11`.

Comment: а как тогда я могу объявить int, который должен сгенерировать рандомное число?

Comment: @ancores: Так в зачем вы пытаетесь генерировать это рандомное число прямо в объявлении? Генерируйте позже.

Answer (score 1):

Вы инициализируете переменную не константным значением.

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rand_num, sup_num;

void probability();

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    rand_num = rand() % 11;

    while(sup_num != rand_num) {
        printf("What is my number?");
        scanf("%d", &sup_num);
        probability();
    }
    return 0;
}

void probability() {
    if(sup_num > rand_num) {
        printf("My number is bigger\n");
    } 
    else if(sup_num < rand_num) {
        printf("My number is less\n");
    } 
    else {
        printf("Gotcha! It is my number!");
    } 
}
```